# AutoFixture - Interface with multiple List<T>'s must have same key in all lists

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture

I have an interface which I need to mock:

```
public interface IDataAccess
{
    List<StaffItem> GetStaff();
    List<RankItem> GetRank();
    List<FleetItem> GetFleet();
    List<ContractItem> GetContract();
    List<BaseItem> GetBase();
}
```

The problem is that each of the classes used for these lists have a common property.  which must match, I am really struggling to create this mock while having a common like of `Id`'s to allow me to test the class's which have this interface injected into to them.

Thanking you all in-advance.

Answer (score 1):

AutoFixture allows to freeze specimens when a specific condition is met. The `[Frozen]` attribute receives a [Matching](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixture.xUnit.net2/Matching.cs) parameter which determines *when* to freeze a specimen. In the sample below the `id` parameter is frozen when the `staffItem.Id` property is to be resolved. Then the same value is injected into `rankItem.Id`:

```
    [Theory, AutoData]
    public void MatchByIdTest(
        [Frozen(Matching.PropertyName)]int id,
        StaffItem staffItem,
        RankItem rankItem)
    {
        Assert.Equal(staffItem.Id, rankItem.Id);
        Assert.NotEqual(staffItem.SomeProp, rankItem.SomeProp);
    }

    public class StaffItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int SomeProp { get; set; }
    }

    public class RankItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int SomeProp { get; set; }
    }
```

The same mechanism can be used in more advanced scenario with a mocking library, e.g. [NSubstitute](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/01/09/NSubstituteAuto-mockingwithAutoFixture/). The sample below uses `AutoConfiguredNSubstituteCustomization` which populates mocks with *some* data but injects the same *id* into all the `Id` properties:

```
    [Theory, AutoConfigNSubstituteData]
    public void MatchByIdTestWithAutoConfigNSubstitute(
        [Frozen(Matching.PropertyName)]int id,
        IDataAccess da)
    {
        var staff = da.GetStaff().First();
        var rank = da.GetRank().First();

        Assert.Equal(staff.Id, rank.Id);
        Assert.NotEqual(staff.SomeProp, rank.SomeProp);
    }

    internal class AutoConfigNSubstituteDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
    {
        public AutoConfigNSubstituteDataAttribute()
            : base(new Fixture()
                    .Customize(new AutoNSubstituteCustomization())
                    .Customize(new AutoConfiguredNSubstituteCustomization()))
        {
        }
    }
```